# Using the method of cylindrical shells

Tags: calculus

Using the method of cylindrical shells,set up an integral for the volume of the torus formed when the circle of radius 2 units centered at (3,0) is revolved about the line x=6.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture.

Note that the circle has equation $(x-3)^2+y^2=4$. The top half of the circle has equation $y=\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}$. The bottom half has equation $y=-\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}$.

Draw a thin vertical strip of width "$dx$" at $x$. The distance of this slice from the line $x=6$ is $6-x$.

The height of that strip is approximately $2\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}$. So when the strip is rotated around the line $x=6$, we get a cylindrical shell of volume approximately
$$2\pi(6-x)(2)\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}\,dx.$$
"Add up" (integrate) from the beginning to the end. So $x$ goes from $1$ to $5$. Our expression for the volume is
$$\int_1^5 2\pi(6-x)(2)\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}\,dx.$$

**Remark:** If I wanted to find the volume, I would probably  reflect everything across the line $x=3$. That leaves the circle alone, but the line $x=6$ becomes the $y$-axis. More comfortable!